# AWS with Terraform: How do I map VPC IDs for peering when each VPC is a separate .tf?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, terraform

I am using Terraform to deploy a hub-and-spoke VPC architecture where a transit/management/infrastructure VPC serves as the communications hub.

Project organization is split into modules & live environment, and the live environment is split up such that each VPC has its own sub-directory.  The problem I'm running into is dynamically retrieving the VPC IDs when I want to create a VPC peering resource -- obviously, this wouldn't be a problem if I instantiated all of my modules in a flat main.tf file, however, that is something I am trying to avoid.

Is it possible to solve this problem with Terraform? It seems to me that with any solution I think of there's the requirement that data be provided statically which maps two VPCs together but the problem is that the VPC ID is assigned at resource creation time and is not something I will know ahead of time.

Do I have to flatten my "live" .tf files or is there another way?  Am I doing something wrong entirely with my file pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using Terraform Modules or just folders with `tf` files? This should be possible with references to the resource outputs. The answer is slightly different depending on if you are using modules. But if you are just using `tf` files in folders you can treat it as "flat". The files are loaded in alphabetical order according to https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/load.html.

Comment: Yes, I am using modules.  The "live environment" files source them in and pass in the necessary variables.  

The problem is that if I use the VPC module and instantiate "Foo" and "Bar", and then instantiate the VPC peering module "Baz" between "Foo" and "Bar" then I in essence have to have every VPC instantiated in the same file which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create our environment in "layers", we build a base networking layer of VPCs and subnets and then a shared infrastructure layer, and then individual application slices that are all part of the application layer. Now terraform code for each layer lives in its own folder and has its own state file. This allows us to update upper layers without having to run through the entire world of terraform managed infrastructure.

Now often upper layers need values from lower layers. Creating an ec2 in application layer needs vpc and subnet information from base layer. We do this through `data.terraform_remote_state`. All of our state files for an environment lives in an s3 bucket with predictable filenames. So in an application slice we'd do:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "base" {
    backend = "s3"
    config {
        bucket = "remote-state-bucket"
        key = "environment-staging/base-layer.tfstate"
        region = "some-region"
    }
}
```

and then we can grab properties that base layer defined as outputs like this:

```
value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.base.some_output}"
```

Comment: I didn't consider the "predictable filenames" part.
Thank you!